# NestJS - Protect access to Swagger UI

Tags: security, swagger-ui, nestjs

I have a project API Rest with NestJS, implements Swagger. Everything working fine, but I need protect the access to Swagger UI.
Is possible protect the Swagger UI with simply user/pass or something like this?

Comment: I am having the same issue too

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to restrict accessing Swagger UI with basic authorization.

You can use this package for basic auth: `express-basic-auth`

After installing `express-basic-auth` you would want to enable this middleware for your endpoint.

```
app.use(['/swagger'], basicAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: {
       [process.env.SWAGGER_USER]: process.env.SWAGGER_PASSWORD,
    },
}));
```

It is important to apply the middleware `app.use(['/swagger'], basicAuth({…})` before you initialize Swagger.

If you want to hide Swagger UI on production, check this article: https://manuel-heidrich.dev/blog/how-to-secure-your-openapi-specification-and-swagger-ui-in-a-nestjs-application/

Information is also taken from that article!