Is there a way to protect the Swagger UI in nest with a passport strategy?
By default, the swagger UI endpoint is not secure in NestJS. In other questions, I've seen people use basicAuth to protect that endpoint. Is it possible to do something similar, but instead of basic auth use a passport strategy (I'm voluntarily not specifying a particular strategy) ?
For demonstration purposes, I've set up a passport BasicStrategy :
@Injectable()
export class HttpStrategy extends PassportStrategy(BasicStrategy) {
    constructor() {
        super((username: string, password: string, done) => {
            if (username === "admin" && password === "admin") {
                return done(null, { username: "admin" });
            }

            return done(null, false);
        });
    }
}

The Swagger init in main.ts is rather standard :
 const config = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle("User API")
        .setDescription("The User API description")
        .setVersion("1.0")
        .addTag("user")
        .build();
    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
    SwaggerModule.setup("swagger", app, document);

How can I use this strategy to protect my swagger endpoint ?

No this suggests the use of basicAuth from "express-basic-auth", it's not using a passport strategy

The following two links will cover you. It has for our project and me, at least.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730842/nestjs-protect-access-to-swagger-ui
https://medium.com/@a16n.dev/password-protecting-swagger-documentation-in-nestjs-53a5edf60fa0

As stated before, those use the basic auth from "express-basic-auth", and not a passport strategy so they don't cover my needs
